# Is there a backup config.txt?

Tags: raspbian, boot

I've changed different parameters in `config.txt` and I forgot to do a backup before I started. I can't really remember which parameters I've changed.

Is there a backup somewhere to restore the default settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download a `config.txt` file from [here](https://github.com/Evilpaul/RPi-config/blob/master/config.txt).  It may look different, but it includes comments to explain all the different settings.

Reading through the comments, I'm not sure if all the warranty comments are 100% accurate or not.  But other than that it contains a lot of useful information!

Comment: Using `rpi-update` will allow you to ensure your **config.txt** has the correct configuration options for your version of the firmware.

Comment: How to generate it from current config? Cause there is no config.txt file in new releases.